# pub get failed (1; Because note requires SDK version >=1.18.0-6.0.pre <2.0.0, version solving failed.)

Tags: flutter, svg

i am trying to use flutter SVG the latest version, but i faced a problem with my SDK version.
i changed it to what the error message said,But i still faces the same problem!

**the error message is:**
pub get failed (1; Because flutter_app depends on flutter_svg >=0.18.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.18.0-6.0.pre <2.0.0, version solving failed.)

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=1.18.0-6.0.pre <2.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.1
```

Answer (score 12):

Probably your project is created flutter beta channel or any downgrade channel. So First run:

- flutter doctor -v

If your current flutter channel is beta ? then run command below:

- flutter channel stable
- flutter upgrade
- flutter pub get

I hope solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

to upgrade your SDK do this in terminal:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

The channel master has the most recent build but it's not stable.
So I advise you to try `flutter channel stable` first.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your project is created years ago.
First run **flutter upgrade**, then update SDK to **sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"**, and then **pub get**

Comment: I am getting this error now  when i try to switch from 2.7.0 to 2.9.0 - 

pub get failed (1; Because Project_name requires SDK version >=2.9.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a different package.
Seems like `flutter_svg` moved to a new flutter beta version and you are on the stable channel.
You need to use an older version of the `flutter_svg` package which uses an older version of flutter